# how to save to database when a post is viewed in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

please how do i save to a database when a post is viewed in cakephp. i have a notification system, and i would love to mark a post as "read" when it is viewed. how do i achieve this?
this is my view code:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Notification->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid notification'));
    }elseif{
        $this->request->data['Notification']['is_read'] = 1;
         $this->Notification->save($this->request->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The notification has been deleted.'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Notification.' . $this->Notification->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('notification', $this->Notification->find('first', $options));

}
```

the problem with this code is that it keeps saving when the post is viewed for the second time. how do i probably implement this capability.